# Find src attribute value of <img> tag in a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have been trying to get the 'src' in img tags inside a javascript variable that contains a block of HTML code dynamically generated/assigned.

Eg:

```
var post_body = "<div>This is an image <img src='abcd.jpg' /> and this is a paragraph <p>hi there</p> Here we have another image <img src='pqrs.jpg' /></div>"
```

the content of the 'post' variable is not predefined and it is dynamic and the HTML code in it always changes. To get the src of the image in it, I did the following. But it does not always work for me.

```
var firstimg = $(post_body).find("img:first").attr("src");
```

I was trying to get the first image of a blog post from the blog post's content but this does not work for some posts having images. How can this be done using javascript or jQuery without failing?

Comment: You are referring to `post_body` while your variable is called `post`.

Comment: Sorry I have changed the question's text accordingly. 'post' must be changed as 'post_body'. That is why I have used post_body thereafter by a mistake while preparing this question.

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/3SLJm/. What is the scenario where it fails?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using plain JavaScript, dump the HTML into a temporary element and extract it:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = post_body;
var firstImage = div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
var imgSrc = firstImage ? firstImage.src : "";
// or, if you want the unresolved src, as it appears in the original HTML:
var rawImgSrc = firstImage ? firstImage.getAttribute("src") : "";
```

Comment: We cant say the string starts with a div or a p tag. It is totally unpredictable and cannot use this answer.

Comment: Um... why does it matter what the string starts with? This code works with any HTML...

Comment: This works but forces the browser to download all of the photos linked in the temporary element.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$(post_body)` to `$(post)`

Try

```
var post = "<div>This is an image <img src='abcd.jpg' /> and this is a paragraph <p>hi there</p> Here we have another image <img src='pqrs.jpg' /></div>";
var firstimg = $(post).find('img:first').attr('src');
```

Comment: Sorry I have changed the question's text accordingly. 'post' must be changed as 'post_body'. That is why I have used post_body thereafter by a mistake while preparing this question.

Comment: This does not work at times due to quotes in the html string so that $(post) gives an error. Needs another way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try adding id to `img` tag and then access it.

```
var oImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
var attr = oImg.getAttribute('src');
```

This is a pure js solution.

Comment: image tags cannot be predefined, they are automatically loaded from an online source.

Answer (score 0):

Late but, if don't want the images to be loaded use the below.

```
var div = document.createElement('template');
div.innerHTML = post_body;
```

if you create div element the remote images are loaded the moment you insert innerHTML, template prevents the requests.